# valgrind xml line number

Tags: c, valgrind

Is it possible to get line numbers in the stack trace in the valgrind XML outptut. I get something like this, but dont get the line number. Am I looking in the wrong place?

```
<stack>
    <frame>
      <ip>0x4C2B60C</ip>
      <obj>/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so</obj>
      <fn>free</fn>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <ip>0x40159D</ip>
      <obj>/home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests</obj>
      <fn>meanqueue_free</fn>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <ip>0x40177A</ip>
      <obj>/home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests</obj>
      <fn>Testmeanqueue_init_is_zero</fn>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <ip>0x402256</ip>
      <obj>/home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests</obj>
      <fn>CuTestRun</fn>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <ip>0x402CCE</ip>
      <obj>/home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests</obj>
      <fn>CuSuiteRun</fn>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <ip>0x40144C</ip>
      <obj>/home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests</obj>
      <fn>RunAllTests</fn>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <ip>0x4014E7</ip>
      <obj>/home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests</obj>
      <fn>main</fn>
    </frame>
</stack>
```

Comment: Did you compile your program with `-g` (debug) option?  If not, do so.